# Find equation of tangent and normal

Tags: calculus, derivatives

**Find the equation of the tangent and normal to the curve at $y = x + 1/x$. At $x=1$.**

I got the gradient of the tangent as 0. 
Then, equation of a tangent

$(y-y1) = m(x-x1)$

$(y-1) =  0 (x-1)$

$y=1$

But the equation of the tangent is y = 2 (as per the answer in the book).

Please do correct me. Thanks.

Comment: Note that $y_1=2$, not 1

Answer (score 0):

Note that $y_1=1+(1/1)=2$, not $1$.

Comment: Ah ... my bad. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome!